# is there a way to split list to chunks?

Tags: lua

I have a very large list (~1M items) and I want to unpack it.
I saw that it is impossible to unpack a list larger than 8000 items so I wanted to chunk it.
Basically this function in python

```py
def chunks(lst, size):
    for i in range(0, len(lst), size):
         yield lst[i:i+size]
```

(for reference I am running the lua script on redis using eval)

Comment: @Piglet it looks like a lua language question, no redis knowledge needed

Comment: @Piglet Lua has one kind of list, which is a table. The rest of those things are not lists.

Comment: `a1, a2, a3,... = table.unpack(lst, i, i+size-1)`

Comment: @Piglet I do know that, the reason I said list and not a table is because I do most of my programing in Python and I am used to the dialect.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff I am not sure how can I implement this in Lua

Comment: The limit on return values is only guaranteed to be at least 1000. That means in order to safely unpack an array bigger than 1M, you'd need 2 layers of nested tables. I'm not sure if that would be worth while. Is @Piglet's answer with the `for` loop sufficient for you?

Answer (score 1):

You could write an iterator that gives you chunks of a certain size.

```
-- an iterator function that will traverse over lst
function chunks(lst, size)
   -- our current index
   local i = 1
   -- our chunk counter
   local count = 0
   return function()
     -- abort if we reached the end of lst
     if i > #lst then return end
     -- get a slice of lst
     local chunk = table.move(lst, i, i + size -1, 1, {})
     -- next starting index
     i = i + size
     count = count + 1
     return count, chunk
   end
end

-- test
local a = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11}
for i, chunk in chunks(a, 2) do
  print(string.format("#%d: %s", i, table.concat(chunk, ",")))
end
```

Output:

```
#1: 1,2
#2: 3,4
#3: 5,6
#4: 7,8
#5: 9,10
#6: 11
```

Read this:

https://www.lua.org/pil/7.1.html

https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.3.5